# Using REX with hasClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several sections in my site that have the `active` class, for example:

```
section.navbar.active
section.terms.active
```

And I want to get all these tags with jquery that have active at the end , is this possible?

I do not want to use:

```
section.navbar.active
section.terms.active
```

OBS: i'm using now because i don't know how to use REGAX properly

Currently i'm using:

```
$('.active').each(function() {
 var active = new Active($(this));
});
```

And i want change to:

```
$('SOMEREGULAREXPTHATMATCHESACTIVECLASSES').each(function() {
 var active..... etc
});
```

Is this possible?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Are you trying to get '.active' or '_active'?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the '_', Ive corrected my answer

Comment: jQuery does not use regular expressions as a selector... So not sure what you are expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use contains operator `*=`

```
$('[class*="active"]')
```

Alterntively, if you want only those explicitly ending with `active`, you can use the ending operator with `$=`

```
$('[class$="active"]')
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6caLuyg8/1/)